# How do I delete or edit Calendar Overlay view?

Tags: calendar, overlay

I created a Calendar Overlay. How do I delete the calendar I selected to show? Also, how do I edit the name of that Calendar I selected for the calendar overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your calendar and click "CALENDAR" in the ribbon
2. Select "Calendars Overlay"
3. Select the calendar you want to delete/edit
4. To delete, hit "Delete", to edit, make changes and hit "OK"